# How to iterate on a Hashmap in html template

Tags: templates, playframework, hashmap, playframework-2.0

I am new to play 2.0 and I am looking for a way to iterate a hashmap in a html template.
I have a form which is bound to a model (Java side) which has a hashmap(Long, List(Article)) attribute called articles.

In an older version, I had an arraylist in place of the hashmap.
In my template, I used the @repeat helper that worked well.

```
@repeat(editBusinessForm("articles"), min = 0) { article =>
    @businessarticle(article)
}
```

I tried several ways to adapt this @repeat or with @for but I couldn't find a way.

I need to display only a part of the articles depending on a category filter. I chose the hashmap to do that but maybe there is an other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

```
@for((key, value) <- yourMap) {
  …
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
@for(key <- yourHashMap.keySet()){
    //get you content
    yourHashMap.get(key)
    //do what you need with the list<articles>
    //example  
    @repeat(yourHashMap.get(key)) { article =>
           @businessarticle(article)
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This code helped me understand how to iterate a map. My problem now is to know how I could do this with form data. Assuming that I have an "editBusinessForm", this won't work :
    @for(key <- editBusinessForm("articles").keySet())
Because editBusinessForm("articles") is a Field and I couldn't find a way to retrieve the associated Map.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: hmm i guess then you can use editBusinessForm("articles").value but it give you a string i don't know if that helps. Have a look around the doc [java field](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/index.html) or [scala field](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Field). There isn't much around to help i guess you only have the value method

Comment: Yes I already had a look around the Field methods and "value" don't fit cause as you say, it gives me a string I can't handle with. I thought I could use the indexes method that works with List but not with Map. I am trying some other workarounds but no results yet. Thank you